# Error in simple_triplet_matrix when creating bigrams with RTextTools and tm

Tags: r, tm

I am trying to create bigrams from text following different approaches proposed on the web. The simplest example is the following:

```
library(RTextTools)
texts <- c("This is the first document.", "This is the second file.", "This is the third text.")
matrix <- create_matrix(texts,ngramLength=3)
```

which results in:

```
Error in simple_triplet_matrix(i = i, j = j, v = as.numeric(v), nrow = length(allTerms),  : 
'i, j, v' different lengths
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In mclapply(unname(content(x)), termFreq, control) :
all scheduled cores encountered errors in user code
2: In simple_triplet_matrix(i = i, j = j, v = as.numeric(v), nrow = length(allTerms),  :
NAs introduced by coercion
```

This is my set up:

```
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
 [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
 [1] graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  stats     methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] tm_0.6-2         NLP_0.1-8        RTextTools_1.4.2 SparseM_1.6     
 [5] SnowballC_0.5.1  reshape2_1.4.1   ggplot2_1.0.0    plyr_1.8.1      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] bitops_1.0-6        caTools_1.17.1      class_7.3-11       
 [4] codetools_0.2-9     colorspace_1.2-4    digest_0.6.8       
 [7] e1071_1.6-4         foreach_1.4.2       glmnet_2.0-2       
 [10] grid_3.1.1          gtable_0.1.2        ipred_0.9-4         
 [13] iterators_1.0.7     lattice_0.20-29     lava_1.4.1         
 [16] MASS_7.3-34         Matrix_1.1-4        maxent_1.3.3.1     
 [19] munsell_0.4.2       nnet_7.3-8          parallel_3.1.1     
 [22] prodlim_1.5.1       proto_0.3-10        randomForest_4.6-10
 [25] Rcpp_0.11.3         rpart_4.1-8         scales_0.2.4       
 [28] slam_0.1-32         splines_3.1.1       stringr_0.6.2      
 [31] survival_2.37-7     tau_0.0-18          tcltk_3.1.1        
 [34] tools_3.1.1         tree_1.0-36
```

Any hints on what is happening?

Comment: I'm not sure. If it helps I get a different error message when I run the code `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : non-character argument`, traceback suggests it's some problem in an lapply internally.